# Trying to resize a flash banner in my header class according to the screen window

Tags: html, flash

This code in the header class for sizing the banner.

I want to resize it according to the browser that the viewer is using.  How can this be done?

```
<div class="header">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    id="ac25c2188119648f18d4e7df823b71eac"
    data="http://imstore.bet365affiliates.com/365_178348-618-214-2-149-1-57326.aspx"
    width="1000"
    height="200"
    style="padding:0px 0px 0px 173px">
```

Comment: would you care to specify your question? what do you mean with "according to the browser the viewer is using"? what do you want to resize and when?

Comment: I just mean I want the banner to be in line with the rest of the site. For example, in chrome when I zoom out the site all stays in line but the banner gets cropped and stays in the left

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know the browsers size in PHP as the size is determined `client side` and PHP is run `server side`.

You could use javascript to change the site once its fully loaded, or you could just enter the width and height as `100%` so that it automatically streched.

If you want to use javascript you could use plain old javascript, but a lot of different browsers use different methods and have different results on the browser window size.

if you are using jQuery it is as simple as:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  //this make sure it starts when its loaded

  $('div.header > object').width($('body').width());
  $('div.header > object').height($('body').height());
})
</script>
```

Atlast there is the fullscreen option for flash, but thats a topic on its own. Check [Exploring full-screen mode in Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html)